# Generate a random value from an array in Google BigQuery standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking to anonymize some marketing data for visualization purposes. To do this, I've created several arrays that replace existing campaign names with anonymized values, such as Campaign 1, Campaign 2, Campaign 3, etc...

I got this working in a PostgreSQL database using the following query:

```
(ARRAY['Campaign 1'::text, 'Campaign 2'::text, 'Campaign 3'::text, 'Campaign 4'::text, 'Campaign 5'::text])[(floor(random() * 5::double precision) + 1::double precision)] AS campaign_name
```

This does what I need in that it randomly assigns a Campaign the numbers 1-5 for each row of data.

I tried to mimic this in BigQuery but am having trouble. I switched random to rand but that did not work. Anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standrad SQL (one of quite many options). Just an example off of generated dummy data

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.dummy_data` AS (SELECT id FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) id)
SELECT id, campaigns[OFFSET(CAST(5 * RAND() - 0.5 AS INT64))] campaign_name
FROM `project.dataset.dummy_data`, (SELECT ['Campaign 1','Campaign 2','Campaign 3','Campaign 4','Campaign 5'] campaigns)
```

Above is assuming that for some reason you want that array to be set
Below version shows that you can avoid it at all

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.dummy_data` AS (SELECT id FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) id)
SELECT id, CONCAT('Campaign ', CAST(1 + CAST(5 * RAND() - 0.5 AS INT64) AS STRING)) campaign_name
FROM `project.dataset.dummy_data`
```

Comment: Your second solution is perfect for what I needed. I didn't even think to concat the string with a random integer - that makes my code much cleaner as well. Thank you!